# Firebird - Ferramentas

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Quais as ferramentas mais utilizadas no gerenciamento do Firebird?

Conheço o IBExpert, mas ele é pago.

Existe algo similar ao IBExpert, mas gratuito?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo(a) ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O próprio site oferece os link para inumeras ferramentas pagas e gratuitas http://firebirdsql.org/en/third-party-tools/

Agora qual é a melhor é algo muito pessoal, tem sempre uma melhor que a outra, mas também tem a que você se adapta melhor.

Algumas ferramentas:

- [Dbeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/)
- [FenixSQL](http://fblib.altervista.org/)
- [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org)
- [FlySpeed SQL Query](http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html)
- [SQLWorkbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/databases.html)
- [SquirellSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins)
- [FirebirdWebAdmin](https://github.com/mariuz/firebirdwebadmin) (aplicação web em PHP)
- [ibWebAdmin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibwebadmin/) (não recebe mais atualizações, mas ainda sim pode usa-la)

O IBExpress tem versão gratuita, é necessário se registrar para baixar http://www.ibexpert.net/downloadcenter/

As seguintes funcionalidades estão ausentes nesta versão:

- Visual Query Builder
- Data Analysis
- SP/Triggers/Views Analyzer
- Database Comparer
- Table Data Comparer
- Log Manager
- Import data
- Print Metadata
- Extract Metadata and extract blob data
- Generate HTML Documentation
- Grant Manager
- To-do list
- Report Manager
- Blob Viewer/Editor
- Database Designer
- Test Data Generator
- ODBC Viewer
- SP/Triggers Debugger
- IBEScript and IBEBlock
- IBExpertBackupRestore
- Database Monitoring
- Trace and audit
- Database Inside

Comment: Obrigada. O IBExpert tem uma versão gratuitta? Se sim, qual limitação?

Comment: @LuizaCH tua pergunta é sobre ferramentas para firebird ou sobre IBExpert afinal de contas?

Comment: *UÉEEE* por que o voto negativo? A gente ajuda e ainda as pessoas vem de inventar picuinhas.

Comment: @Luhhh atualizei a resposta e coloquei sobre o IBExpert, não entendi porque vc me negativou, eu respondi o que esta escrito exatamente na sua pergunta, eu só perguntei se você queria saber se era sobre IBExpert ou sobre firebird. Não tem motivo para achar ruim, aqui não é um fórum e sim um site de perguntas e respostas, a pergunta deve ser objetiva, assim como a resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei em que linguagem você programa, mas para o Delphi por exemplo, versão 7 tem o SqlExplorer que já vem embutido no Delphi, apesar de ser uma ferramenta muito simples. Nas versões mais recentes do Delphi, tem o FireDac explorer, que é o SQLExplorer das versões atuais, porém são ferramentas simples.